# SQL Server Linked Server to PostgreSQL Turkish Character Issue

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, character-encoding, collation, linked-server

I have added a PostgreSQL linked server to my SQL Server with help from [this blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/). My problem is when I use the query below, I am having problems with Turkish characters.

Query on Microsoft SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OpenQuery(CARGO, 'SELECT taxno  ASACCOUNTNUM, title AS NAME FROM view_company');
```

Actual results:

> MUSTAFA ÞAHÝNALP

Expected results:

> MUSTAFA ŞAHİNALP

Comment: What is your server collation? What is the datatype of title on the PostgreSQL server? Try `'SELECT taxno  ASACCOUNTNUM, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128),title) AS NAME FROM view_company'`

Comment: view_company located on PostgreSQL Database so when use query  select * from view_company in pgAdmin, results return correct. My problem is when i use above query in MS Sql, i'm havins problems with Turkish characters.

Comment: How is the linked server configured? Is `use server collation` enabled?

Comment: My Microsoft Sql Server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. I don't have Turkish character problem with my sql server. Also i couldn't see collaction settings while adding linked server to my Sql server.

Comment: You need to change the option after creating the linked server. .in SSMS, go to Server Objects, linked servers, and go to the properties of the linked server. Under options play with various combinations of "use server collation" and "collation compatible". Also, use a person's `@` login name to notify them of your message, else they won't see it unless they happen to check back later.

Comment: @MehmetArdin Just curious, which option(s) worked?

Comment: Hi srutzky, i have solved with this query. thank you for you support. EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'linked_server_name',
                     @optname='use remote collation',
                     @optvalue=N'true';

EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'linked_server_name',
                     @optname='collation name',
                     @optvalue=N'Turkish_100_CI_AS';

Comment: @MehmetArdin (sorry, I didn't see your comment until just now -- you need to prefix the login name with a `@` in order for that person to get notified of your comment, but you can only do that with 1 login per comment). You are quite welcome, and thanks for sharing which option worked. I have updated my answer with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the source encoding is 8-bit Extended ASCII using Code Page 1254 -- [Windows Latin 5 (Turkish)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195056.aspx). If you follow that link, you will see the Latin5 chart of characters to values. The value of the `Ş` character -- "Latin Capital Letter S with Cedilla" -- is **222** (Decimal) / **DE** (Hex). Your local server (i.e. SQL Server) has a default Collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` which is also 8-bit Extended ASCII, but using Code Page 1252 -- [Windows Latin 1 (ANSI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx). If you follow that link, you will see the Latin1 chart that shows the `Þ` character -- "Latin Capital Letter Thorn" -- also having a value of **222** (Decimal) / **DE** (Hex). This is why your characters are getting translated in that manner.

There are a few things you can try:

1. Use [sp_serveroption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178532.aspx) to set the following two options:

   ```sql
   EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'linked_server_name',
                        @optname='use remote collation',
                        @optvalue=N'true';

   EXEC sp_serveroption @server=N'linked_server_name',
                        @optname='collation name',
                        @optvalue=N'Turkish_100_CI_AS';
   ```

   Not sure if that will work with PostgreSQL as the remote system, but it's worth trying at least. Please note that this requires that all remote column collations be set to this particular value: Turkish / Code Page 1254.
2. Force the Collation per each column:

   ```sql
   SELECT [ACCOUNTNUM], [NAME] COLLATE Turkish_100_CI_AS
   FROM   OPENQUERY(CARGO, 'SELECT taxno AS ACCOUNTNUM, title AS NAME FROM view_company');
   ```
3. Convert the string values (just the ones with character mapping issues) to `VARBINARY` and insert into a temporary table where the column is set to the proper Collation:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE #Temp ([AccountNum] INT, [Name] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Turkish_100_CI_AS);

   INSERT INTO #Temp ([AccountNum], [Name])
     SELECT [ACCOUNTNUM], CONVERT(VARBINARY(100), [NAME])
     FROM  OPENQUERY(CARGO, 'SELECT taxno AS ACCOUNTNUM, title AS NAME FROM view_company');

   SELECT * FROM #Temp;
   ```

   This approach will first convert the incoming characters into their binary / hex representation (e.g. `Ş` --> `0xDE`), and then, upon inserting `0xDE` into the `VARCHAR` column in the temp table, it will translate `0xDE` into the expected character of that value *for Code Page 1254* (since that is the Collation of that column). The result will be `Ş` instead of `Þ`.

**UPDATE**

Option # 1 worked for the O.P.